# Can I take communion in the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, communion, presbyterianism

I was baptized and raised in the Presbyterian Church. I am a speech language pathologist.  For the past 12 months have been volunteering my time tutoring a Cathololic priest who was born in a third world country and who resides in the US.  We read the Gospels together.

I help him with his pronunciations, inflections and intonations, etc. of the English language as well as interpretion and discussion of the Gospels he inturn reads at mass each week.

He has grown immensley where initially he had great difficulty sending the messages of the Gospels.

He has never asked me if I am Catholic.   I go to his church to listen to his readings periodically.   I would love to take communion during the service but I don't feel welcomed by the Catholic Church even though I am providing a great service to all.  Can I take communion if I am not a Catholic?

Comment: You have to make the decision, it is not that there are people going to ask you. Most churches do allow members from other churches when they are full members. Most people will discuss this things with a priest or minister if they feel they can not make the decision themselves. Your friend the priest will know you are not RC, as you do not react as one. Better talk it over with him. He might have different considerations from western born/raised/trained priests and you better ask than do something that your friend might be hurt by.

Comment: This question should have been asked at (or migrated to) Christianity.SE, but on the facts given, the answer is No. I'm surprised you're not *welcomed,* but unless you are a member of the Catholic Church you're not actually *eligible* to take communion. Not even every Catholic is.